# How to pass textbox.text from an application form to open mdi child in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have been looking for a way to pass a textbox value from an open form that was called from a mdi child, back to the calling mdi child form.

I have researched many ways and am unable to solve this particular issue myself.  Most answers involve passing between two forms, passing from mdi parent to mdi child, or between two mdi children.

My application needs to pass a textbox value from a form to a mdi child.  This is one of the code samples that I have tried;

frmCalendar.txtSun1.Text = Me.txtInsert.Text

This form is called from the mdi child specifically to input appointments in the textbox of the mdi child.

This is how I am opening the form from frmCalendar:

```
Private Sub txtSun1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSun1.DoubleClick
    Dim cInput As New frmInput
    cInput.WindowState = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    cInput.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    cInput.Visible = True
    cInput.lblTextRecieve.Text = Me.txtSun1.Text
    cInput.txtInsert.Text = Me.txtSun1.Text
    cInput.lblDate.Text = Me.gbMonthName.Text & " " & su1.Text & ", " & Format(Now, "yyyy")
    cInput.lblSource.Text = "txtSun1"
    cInput.Focus()
    cInput.Show()
End Sub
```

This is the line I need to work when frmInput closes:

```
frmCalendar.txtSun1.Text = Me.txtInsert.Text
```

txtInsert is the only textbox on the frmInput form.

Help!

Comment: How are you showing the form

Comment: This is how I am opening the form from frmCalendar:

Answer (score 0):

As long as the textbox modifier remains the default(`Friend`), create the form that you're calling as a new object(`Dim newcalendar As New frmCalendar()`) .  Thus even after it closes you'll be able to access the textbox as a property of the form(`txtInsert.Text = newcalendar.txtSun1.Text`).

Comment: This does not really help me. I am trying to add the text from the new form to the calling mdi child as the new form is closing. I have updated my original question with my calling code. Could you please take another look?

Comment: Instead of using `Show()` use `ShowDialog()`.  This way the calling form is notified when the new form closes, and you can extract the text from the new form's textbox.  This gives the added advantage of reacting to the user cancelling the form.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your InputForm add a handler to its FormClosing event. That way you are able to extract the data you need as the form is closing.

Something like this.

```
Private Sub txtSun1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSun1.DoubleClick
    Dim cInput As New frmInput
    AddHandler frmInput.FormClosing, AddressOf InputFormClosing 'Note change adding the handler to the closing event
    cInput.WindowState = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    cInput.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    cInput.Visible = True
    cInput.lblTextRecieve.Text = Me.txtSun1.Text
    cInput.txtInsert.Text = Me.txtSun1.Text
    cInput.lblDate.Text = Me.gbMonthName.Text & " " & su1.Text & ", " & Format(Now, "yyyy")
    cInput.lblSource.Text = "txtSun1"
    cInput.Focus()
    cInput.Show()
End Sub

'EventHandler to get information from the closing form
Private Sub InputFormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    txtSun1.Text = DirectCast(sender, Form3).txtInsert.Text
End Sub
```